# Is every undefined symbol associated with a software library it comes from?

Tags: word-order

The affirmative sentence is:

> Every undefined symbol is associated with a software library it comes from.

I'm trying to make a question:

> Is every undefined symbol associated with a software library it comes from?

but it just looks very unnatural. Is it really so? It can be tending to be read like this

> Is (every undefined symbol associated with a software library) (it comes from)?
>
> Is (every undefined symbol associated with a software library it comes from) (???)?

and to cause a confusion. While the intended structure is

> Is (every undefined symbol) (associated with a software library it comes from)?

How this question can be reformulated to sound naturally?

Comment: Why are you adding *it comes from*? Why not just say: *Every undefined symbol is associated with a source name*? You wouldn't say *I have two parents I came from.*

Comment: I have modified the sentence. Now it is very close to the original.

Comment: If you added *that* before *it comes from*, it might make the sentence clearer.

Answer (score 1):

Your original sentence might be

> Every undefined symbol is associated with **the** software library it came from.

So your question might be

> Is every undefined symbol associated with **a** software library?
>   Is every undefined symbol associated with **the** software library where it is defined?

The answer is "***yes***".